# Is there any CC licensed illustrations web resource like flickr?

Tags: graphics, flickr

I maintain a blog about preschool children. I usually get good, open source licensed (creative commons) photos from flickr. Flickr is very rich in terms of quality photos. But the problem is that flickr doesn't have too many illustrations.

I wonder if there is a rich resource like flickr which is specifically focused on illustrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [OpenClipArt project](http://openclipart.org/) - seems to be fairly extensive.

Answer (score 1):

While the collection is not quite as extensive, you could try various categories in a [Wikimedia Commons image search](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aPictures_and_images) such as *illustrations* or *drawings* (or even *drawings by children* if that's more what you are after).

Answer (score 1):

Google & Yahoo let you specify filters to restrict image results to those that have CC licensing.

I built a JavaScript-based [image meta-search app](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2010/04/image-meta-search-with-searchlite.html) that fetches images with liberal licensing. [Check it out](http://www26.brinkster.com/mvark/codegallery/imagesearchlite.htm)..